# Cannot convert 1.0 to EagerTensor of dtype int32

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, svm

I'm trying to use keras to make a cnn and use a SVM after the dense layer of cnn as classifier. So I'm trying to get the output after the dense layer.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5), input_shape=(12,800), strides=2, padding='valid', activation='relu'))
model.add(AveragePooling1D(pool_size=2,strides=2,padding='same'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(7 ,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

My code for getting the output after the dense layer

```
inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
functor = k.function([inp, k.learning_phase()], outputs )   # evaluation function

# Testing
test = np.random.random(input_shape)[np.newaxis,...]
layer_outs = functor([test, 1.])
```

But I'm getting this error
**TypeError: Cannot convert 1.0 to EagerTensor of dtype int32**

Comment: Change 1. (a float) to 1 (an integer)

Comment: hi, if you remove the k.learning_phase()  and call the function using only "test" input then your example works perfectly. In fact, K.learning_phase just helps to determine if it is training or testing and you can set it separately as K.set_learning_phase. If you like this approach I can upload my example. Rememeber the API for K.function takes input,output, updates, kwargs as shown here https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/function. For more on K.function see this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142181/whats-the-purpose-of-keras-backend-function/50368714.  Best

Comment: Hi, if you are willing to disable eager execution  tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution() then your model should also work fine as it is. Best